# How much does a resist bonus on armor reduce damage by?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

Some armors and accessories will have an effect on them which modifies resistance to a certain damage type, followed by a varying number of arrows indicating the bonus. For example, the **Adama Armor** has *Physical Resist +1*. Although having resistance to physical damage would be nice, it's difficult to determine how well compares to other armor sets without knowing how much physical damage is reduced by.

How much does a resist bonus on armor reduce damage by?

Comment: It usually takes people a while to figure this stuff out or it's in Japanese. But from experience, everything is situational. What's good vs one boss will likely not be great against another. If you're on a floor where nothing is doing physical damage then clearly it's a bad choice, and vice versa.